# Can't stablish TCP connections into a Hyper-V Centos VM

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v, tcp, centos-7

I've set up an internal network with a VPN gateway on Hyper-V on Windows 10. It works fine in the sense that all VMs can communicate with one another and with the external world.

The problem happens when I try to establish any sort of TCP connection from the host to the guests, ssh connections are my main use case, but I've tried other protocols (HTTP, FTP, etc) and they don't work either.

Funny enough, I can ping the VMs from the host, so ICMP is fine, but any TCP connection doesn't make it to the VMs. I've verified it with tcpdump on the VMs.

Yes, I've disabled the firewall on the Linux VMs (tcpdump -F), and yes, the VM's can ssh to one another.

Thanks

PS: I proficient on Linux but not on Windows

Comment: Can you try disabling various kinds of hardware offloading via `ethtool`?

Comment: @pimp-juice-it They are on the same network, I've defined an IP on the host that's connected to interface "4", the same one used by the VMs. `New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.64.1 -PrefixLength 20 -InterfaceIndex 4`. The VMs IP's are also contained in the same subnet, 192.168.64.0/20. As I said, I can ping the VMs from the host, and viceversa, but I cannot stablish any sort of TCP connection.

Comment: @pimp-juice-it I followed these instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network

Comment: My setup may be a little different here with the system I have access to at the moment. It's actually Hyper-V on Server 2012 R2 Data Center and it's setup with 3 of the 4 NICs as virtual switches as "External" network and the TCP/IP properties of those virtual switches from the host "Network Connections" have the static IP, subnet mask, Default Gateway, and DNS setup on them pointing to the internal network or whatever. Then I assign each VM to one of the 3 virtual switches with a static IP, DNS, etc. on the same network. Not sure if that'd help you much or not but that's what I see here.

Comment: And lastly and honestly, when I setup this server, I did not use any of the PowerShell commands and just did it all from the GUI of the host server and/or Hyper-V on the host so that may make a difference as well if you ran some command you didn't need but simple creating the switches as "external" and ensuring the option of **Allow management operating system to share this network adapter** from the **Virtual Switch Manager** and assigning the IP setting via the host Network Connections area worked well in my case for this particular system I'm looking at.

Comment: But if I use an "external" switch, then the guests are going to be exposed directly to the same external network my worstation is connected to, right? That means I'd need to secure an IP for them. My company's DHCP server only assign IP's to their list of registered Ethernet MACs.

Comment: Before you get too involved though, simply disable the Hyper-V host Windows Firewall and try access those different ports/protocols because if it works with the Host Hyper-V Windows Firewall disabled, then that should confirm you need to open up the ports needed for that traffic. This should be simple enough to try and eliminate I suppose just in case.

Comment: > the Host Hyper-V Windows Firewall

Are you talking about something in Hyper-V, or the host's own native firewall mechanism? (`iptables` in this case, since they are Linux VMs). If it's `iptables` then, yes, I've already disabled it, no change, if it is some other sort of firewall then please tell me more about it.

Comment: Disable the Hyper-V host Windows firewall and then test it all out afterwards: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505 is a link but go to **Control Panel** > **Windows Firewall** > click on **Turn Windows Firewall on or off** > select all the **Turn off Windows Firewall** > OK. Now test and see if the problem still exists or not. If not, the FW is blocking the traffic, etc. at the Hyper-V host Windows FW level. This is the Windows 10 OS Control Panel which is the Hyper-V host in your case too by the way.

Comment: I'm not allowed to disable firewall by my IT dept. I'm in a very huge company and there is no way I can circumvent this.

Comment: I'm a hyper-v admin though, and I was wondering if there is anything in hyper-v, some sort of internal hyper-v firewall, that I can tinker with.